# Add column field to a table - cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, cakephp

I need to alter a table to add a Column to it. I need to do it in cakephp 3.
I have tried below code from [Schema System Cakephp-3](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/schema-system.html#schema-table-objects)

```
$result = new Table('dummys');
$result->addColumn('my_field', ['type' => 'binary']);
```

This code should create a new Table with the field `'my_field'` but its not doing that.

I have also tried it with already created table but still no luck.

Please help me on this guys as I need to create the field in table from Cakephp only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This code should create a new Table with the field 'my_field' but its not doing that.

No, it should not.

You want [migrations](https://book.cakephp.org/migrations/2/en/index.html), not schema.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.  :)